# Android fastscroll label text size

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view with fast scrolling enabled. Everything worked perfectly until I had to add a feature to sort not only alphabetically but also by date.

Sorting works great and the scrolling as well, however, there is an issue with the fast scroll label view (not sure what the component name is).

[image]
this is on Android 4

[image]
this is on Android 5

I would like to know, if there is a style property to change the text size or if it is possible to somehow style the whole view. In general, I'd prefer to change the text size only because it is just too large.

**UPDATE**

I found that there is a style on API 21+ `@android:style/Widget.Material.FastScroll` which allows to change the text size. This however does not work for android 4. Is there a similar property?

Comment: I think you can write your own implementation that fits you needs, for inspiration you can look here https://github.com/rno/Android-ScrollBarPanel

Comment: I'll take a look, but it seems it won't work as I already use a library for the sticky list headers. I'll try to extend the sticky list and wire my custom implementation of the scrollbar panel, but it will be great if there is a simpler way. Nonetheless, much appreciated